# Ensuring consistency for parallel Database Updates in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, parallel-processing

I'm currently developing a REST API which inserts entries to a database via POST.
I'm now wondering whether the following pseudo-code can cause race conditions.

This is the code displayed as pseudocode:

```
entryCandidate (passed parameter to function for new entry)

var all_entries = get_all_entries_from_database
var alreadyBooked = false
foreach currentEntry in all_entries
    if (currentEntry.time == entryCandidate.time)
        alreadyBooked = true

if !alreadybooked
    database.add(entryCandidate)
```

Now my question: Since reading the table in step 1 and iterating / writing in step 2, could there be another instance inserting an conflicting entry to the database, so I end up with two conflicting entries?

If this is an issue, how is this usually solved in EF?

Code is running, but I'm wondering if it can be affected by race conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't really related to the SQL _language_. I suggest you replace the <sql> tag with a tag for the dbms you're using. (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: Pseudocode isn't useful. It doesn't show what *actually* happens and in code each minor detail matters. But the obvious answer to you question is: yes.

Comment: You need to read up on optimistic and pessimistic concurrency and decide a) which solution meets your business needs and b) how you will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

EF uses client-side optimistic concurrency.  See [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations).

> EF Core implements optimistic concurrency, which assumes that concurrency conflicts are relatively rare. In contrast to pessimistic approaches - which lock data up-front and only then proceed to modify it - optimistic concurrency takes no locks, but arranges for the data modification to fail on save if the data has changed since it was queried. This concurrency failure is reported to the application, which deals with it accordingly, possibly by retrying the entire operation on the new data.
>
> In EF Core, optimistic concurrency is implemented by configuring a
> property as a concurrency token. The concurrency token is loaded and
> tracked when an entity is queried - just like any other property.
> Then, when an update or delete operation is performed during
> SaveChanges(), the value of the concurrency token on the database is
> compared against the original value read by EF Core.

Comment: That won't pick up on 2 inserts for the calendar time though?

Comment: That is true. I tested it but since i do not read from any existing values this method doesn't work. I would need to check whether new entries have been added to the table.